# "Iterate" over constants defined inside a namespace

Tags: c++, boost, macros

Say I have a bunch of constants define inside a namespace:

```
namespace FooConstants{
    const string foo1 = "foo1";
    const string foo2 = "foo2";
    //...
    const string fooN = "fooN";
}
```

Is it possible to use Boost to "iterate" over these constants names? Something like a macro which expands generating `foo1`, `foo2` to `fooN` and lets me do something with each. I believe this can be done using some Boost library, but I couldn't find it.

By the way, is there a proper name for this kind of technique?

**Edit**: I was asked to clarify if this is meant to be solved at compile or run time. The answer is compile time: I want to generate code that operates over all the constants.

Comment: Do you know `N` before hand?

Comment: Assume it's hard coded, but I want to solve the general case (any N value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your example to start the constant numbering at 0 to simplify the comma generation, but you can definitely do this, with things happening at compile time:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace FooConstants{
    const std::string foo0 = "foo0";
    const std::string foo1 = "foo1";
    const std::string foo2 = "foo2";
    const std::string foo3 = "fooN";
#define N 3
}

namespace metadata {

const std::map<int, std::string> constants = {

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
   BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) \
   std::make_pair(n, BOOST_PP_CAT(FooConstants::foo,n))

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (0, N)

#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
 };
}

int main() {}
```

Here the preprocessor generates an initalizer_list which can initalise a `const std::map`.  You could do more crazy const things with constexpr and templates if you wanted though.

Just because it's possible doesn't mean I'd recommend doing it in a real code base though.

Comment: Looks good. But why would you discourage doing something like this? (asides from the fact that it makes the code look a little ugly )

Comment: @dario_ramos It's "odd code" which means that the maintenance costs will always be higher. Couple that with the fact that I'm not convinced it wins you anything over just sticking your constants into a map to begin with I don't think it's something I'd be trying to use in anger.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the [Boost Preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

[BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html) seems to be most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

That would require metadata which c++ does not have.  You could come up with some customs macros and use convention like foomax and foomin but there is no library I know of.

Comment: @dario Your question doesn't really say whether the "do something with each" should happen at compile time or at runtime. Maybe you should clarify.

Comment: That uses a macro and convention I took the question to mean at run time which would not be possible.

Comment: It's possible to do at runtime too if the constants are exported. Not portable but still feasible.